# Get Monodevelop to use the downloaded GtkSharp

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I installed the GtkSharp 3.22.24.36 package via *Project* > *Add NuGet Packages...*, which completed successfully. But now Monodevelop can't decide which version of GtkSharp to use (3.22.24.36 or the in-built one, 2.12).
[image]

If I uncheck `gtk-sharp` in the *Edit references...* dialog, it tells me that I can't use the UI designer without it.
[image]

How do I get Monodevelop to use the downloaded GtkSharp (3.22)?

Comment: It's possible the designer only works with v2, so you might be on your own writing forms with v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop comes with a custom version of Gtk2 + [Xwt](https://github.com/mono/xwt) bundled. If you plan to use Gtk3, then the designer must be deactivated, since it won't work with Gtk3.

My advice, anyway, no matter which toolkit you use, is to avoid using the designer. As soon as you involve the designer, you code heavily depends on the IDE you use (Visual Studio, MonoDevelop, NetBeans... you name it).

Creating user interfaces "by hand" is no longer traumatic as it was in the 90's with the Windows API. For example, you can find a very good [Gtk# tutorial in ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/).

User Interface Toolkits are actually very similar, they change the name of widgets and sometimes provide a slightly different layout, but they are all mostly the same, no matter it is WinForms or Gtk(for C#), Swing (Java), or Qt (C++ and others).

Comment: You're right. I did some digging and found that GtkSharp 3.x is community-supported. Only GtkSharp 2.12 is officially supported by the Mono project. But the worse thing is there doesn't seem to be any documentation for GtkSharp 3.x, so I think I'll just use GtkSharp 2.12 since I'm not a GTK wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an older question but things changed. Abandon MonoDevelop, just use the .NET Standard bound implementation of [GtkSharp](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp). You can then literally design interface using glade xml files, using official Glade application from GTK+. You can find it [here](https://glade.gnome.org/).

With the current push from MS to abandon Framework in favor of Core, we finally succumbed when we figured out they will kill Framework (which they just did with .NET 5 announcement), but we also used the opportunity to investigate other options for our ports of LoBs to core. We discovered GtkSharp as WinForms replacement and [AvaloniaUI](http://avaloniaui.net/) as WPF replacement, which not only work perfectly but also truly work cross-platform. We ported several applications already and actually moved more then half of business work stations from Windows to Linux.

Comment: Which IDE are you using on Linux? VS Code?

Comment: Nope, VS Code is no IDE, its a plugin-based notepad (like notepad++, for example). It does not even support solutions, let alone more advanced project control. Its a toy for front end people. For production work we use [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/).